# WPF Combobox binding to update multiple textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

i have a class

```
class Names {
public int id get; set;};
public string name {get ; set};
public string til {set{
if (this.name == "me"){
return "This is me";
}
}
```

i have a list (ListNames) which  contains Names added to it and binding with a combo box

```
<ComboBox  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=id, Mode=TwoWay,
 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding
 ListNames}" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedValuePath="id" />
```

every thing works

i want to display the "Tip" on another label field when user selects an item.

is it possible?

help!

Comment: You mean the ToolTip? or the 'til' property in your Names class? Should it be Tip? Off topic, but I'd rename your class to Name, public properties should start with capital letter. Are you using MVVM? Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your ViewModel would solve your problem.

Comment: i am using INotifyPropertyChanged  but not MVVM

Comment: Like @Miiite suggests using MVVM pattern would make things easier. Binding your label text to the selected item in your ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using MVVM.

You need to create in your window's viewmodel, a property "CurrentName" of type "Names", binded to the ComboBox SelectedItem property.
This property must raise the NotifyPropertyChanged event.

Then, bind your label field, to this "CurrentName" property.
When the SelectedIem property will change on the combobox, your label field will then be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:
Your Model:

```
public class Names 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tip {
        get
        {
            return Name == "me" ? "this is me" : "";
        }
    }
}
```

Your ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Names> _namesList;
    private Names _selectedName;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        NamesList = new ObservableCollection<Names>(new List<Names>
            {
                new Names() {Id = 1, Name = "John"},
                new Names() {Id = 2, Name = "Mary"}
            });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Names> NamesList
    {
        get { return _namesList; }
        set
        {
            _namesList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Names SelectedName
    {
        get { return _selectedName; }
        set
        {
            _selectedName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And finally your View:

```
<Window x:Class="Combo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Combo="clr-namespace:Combo"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <Combo:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NamesList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedName}"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=SelectedName.Name}"/>
</StackPanel>
```